# Error when booting Windows XP - WindowsNT Has Found Only 495k Of Low Memory. 512 of low memory is required to run Windows NT

Tags: windows-xp, boot

Are you getting this error message when starting your computer running Windows XP?

> WindowsNT Has Found Only 495k Of Low Memory. 512 of low memory is required to run Windows NT. You may need to upgrade your computer or run a configuration program provided by the manufacturer.

Try the suggestions below to fix this issue.

Comment: Asking and answering your own question at the same time is encouraged, as it's a way to share knowledge - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/. The question does need to be rewritten though.

Answer (score 1):

If you see this error message when computer is first booting up, here are a few tests you can do:

Typically this has nothing to do with RAM memory, but rather a corrupt boot setting being read by Windows. You are probably running Win XP, but it says WindowsNT due to the pre-boot process.

1. Start the computer from a WinXP factory install CD and go into Recovery console. Change Directory to C:\ and run FIXMBR  Then run FIXBOOT  Then restart the computer. If it was a corrupt boot setting you will typically be able to get windows started.

If that did not work, test the computer's memory:

2. Use BIOS on startup to check ram. Watch your screen at startup, looking for a clue on which key to press to go into BIOS. Typically it is DELETE key or F2. Once BIOS loads, poke around and look for a fast boot / hidden boot setting and turn it off. This will allow you to watch the system memory being tested at BIOS load time. Typically this indicates if memory is ok.
3. Search the web for MEMTEST software and burn to a boot disk to test your memory chips.
4. Run diagnostics on the motherboard using software from the mobo manufacturer. If you made it this far, your mobo is probably in need of replacement.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of trying all those you can try this :

- load bios with the steps given above and press F5 to load defaults in BIOS press <kbd>Y</kbd> to save and then,
- press <kbd>F10</kbd> to save and exit press <kbd>Y</kbd> to save.
- Then it will restart the computer and then,
- it will ask to activate windows which happened in my case.